# Forcing the specifying of a vm-name when running vagrant provision/destroy/up

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile

When trying to up, provision, or destroy a vagrant machine you need to specify a vm-name (as defined in the vagrantfile) if you only want to effect one machine (e.g. run `vagrant up local; vagrant up uatk vagrant up production;`) - if you fail to do this then the changes effect all the virtual machines.

Therefore typing "`vagrant destroy`" rather than "`vagrant destroy local`" downs all your machines.  Is it possible to either:-

a) exclude a virtual machine when no machines are specified

b) force the specifying of a vm-name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify primary machine in Vagrant, so that when you run Vagrant command without specifying target, it will run on the primary machine and not all the machines in your Vagrantfile.

Marking primary machine is done by by setting the primary flag:

```
config.vm.define "web", primary: true do |web|
  # ...
end
```

[See the Docs for more info.](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/multi-machine/index.html)